# Machine level authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication

When I submit a form to other page in my ASP.NET site, it asks for windows authentication. How do I remove this?

Comment: Please state your version of IIS and .net and the server OS version.

Comment: I use Brinkster mini package. It is .Net 3.5. IIS 6, Windows Server 2003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to set up windows authentication. One is in IIS and one is in web.config. So basically you need to check that there is no `<authentication mode="windows">` tag in your main web.config or in a web.config in the specific folder where the aspx page in question is located. Furthermore you also need to go to the IIS manager (`inetmgr`) and make sure that windows authentication is not enabled in the folder in question.